# Magento 1 CE - How to create a diferent category for each Multistore

Tags: magento

Thank you for reading..

I have created a multistore site based on 4 diferents subdomains domain1.site.com domain2.site.com and so on, everything works, i have diferent logo and design for each site, but i need to enable and disable categories already created for each site, is this possible?, i dont mean root category, i need to show a category for one site, and other category for other site, is this possible via admin panel or at least via code?

I have tried to create root category and disable category by category for each store view.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Its possible but quite complicated. let me explain you how you reach that.

1. You need to create one custom category attribute and just set the value in which you want to display that category.
2. In category page (coding side) you just need to check this attribute value and write your condition according to that.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new Root category into magento admin

```
Admin >> Catalog >> Manage Categories
```

Now Go to Manage Store in

```
Admin >> System >> Manage Stores
```

Click on your new Store for which you need to set different category.